# Slim 3 and Twig: when you click on the Buy button, the value from the field should appeared in Route

Tags: php, ajax, twig, slim

I have a problem how to do so: when you click on the Buy button, the value from the field should appeared in Route?

For example: I have a Quantity field and a Buy button. By clicking on the Buy button, route should look like this: ../slug/quantity. for example: ../product-coffee/2

the code below:

Route:

```
$app->get('/cart/add/{slug}/{quantity}', ['Shop\Controllers\CartController', 'add'])->setName('cart.add');
```

View:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" value="2">
<a href="{{ path_for('cart.add', { slug: product.slug, quantity: 1 }) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Buy</a>
```

Part of controller:

```
public function add($slug, $quantity, Request $request, Response $response, Router $router)
{
  $product = $this->product->where('slug', $slug)->first();

  if (!$product) {
    return $response->withRedirect($router->pathFor('home'));
  }

  try {
    $this->basket->add($product, $quantity);
  } catch (QuantityExceededException $e) {
    //
  }

  return $response->withRedirect($router->pathFor('cart.index'));
}
```

Where: `quantity: 1`, I need to value was taken from the input field

Comment: You will need to adjust the quantity part with javascript...

Comment: You cannot possibly know what the quantity the user will have when you render the page...you need to add javascript to the button to generate the proper link.

Comment: The solution was easy.. And without javascript. I had to think a little.